# How to rename field using jdt

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

```
Public class RenameClass{
    private static final String TITLE= "title";
    Public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println(TITLE)
   }
```

}

By using jdt, I want to remove the field and in place of `TITLE` I want to rename with the value....
I want to rename like below:

```
Public class RenameClass{
    Public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("title")
   }
```

}

Please provide any reference or source for implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the existing [Inline Constant](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20refactoring/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/InlineConstantRefactoring.java) refactoring.

*Not to be confused with Rename refactorings, btw.*

Comment: If you have any reference how to do...can you please share.. I tried by using RenameSupport but it is not working..

Comment: Thanks for your help .I got the solution

Comment: @pvprasanth, to make this thread useful for others, please explain what exactly you achieved with a hint on how. If re-using the referenced InlineConstantRefactoring.java is indeed part of the solution, then accepting the answer would seem appropriate :)